# Liquid Script: Convert string to number in order to display as money

Tags: shopify, liquid, dotmailer

I'm trying to display a floating point value as money in liquid script. It appears to only allow you to do this to numbers, however I can't convert a string to a number (despite following advice on SO as below:)

```
{% assign teststring = '202.2400' %}
{% assign testnumeric = 202.2400 %}
teststring: {{ teststring }} <br/>
testnumeric: {{ testnumeric }} <br/>

teststring as money: {{ teststring |money: "GBP" }} <br/>
testnumeric as money: {{ testnumeric |money: "GBP" }} <br/>

{% assign testStringAsNumeric = teststring | plus: 45 %}
test convert teststring to numeric: {{ testStringAsNumeric }} <br/>
test show above as money: {{ testStringAsNumeric |money: "GBP" }}
```

The output is:

```
teststring: 202.2400 
testnumeric: 202.24 
teststring as money: 202.2400 
testnumeric as money: £202.24 
test convert teststring to numeric: 202.24000 
test show above as money: 202.24000
```

What I want is to show the string value (teststring) as money. So I need to convert to a number and then display as money.

I've also tried the times filter e.g.

```
{% assign testStringAsNumeric = teststring | times: 1 %}
```

test show above as money: {{ testStringAsNumeric |money: "GBP" }}

But this returns an error:

```
test show above as money: System.Linq.Enumerable+d__112`1[System.String]
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Just to clarify the desired output is the output from `testnumeric as money: £202.24` but I need this applying to a string, thanks

Answer (score 2):

So there are a couple things with this question I'd like to address.

**Firstly**, when using the money filter, the number is interpreted as `cents`, eg.

```
Input: {{ 2000 | money }}

Output: $20.00
```

Because of this, your line below, once correctly formatted, will display `$2.47`.

`test show above as money: {{ testStringAsNumeric |money: "GBP" }}`

**Second**, the way to set which currency is going to be used by the `money` filter is inside Shopify admin, rather than inside the liquid drop as a parameter. Because of this, once you set your currency inside Shopify's admin, all you'll have to write is:

`test show above as money: {{ testStringAsNumeric | money }}`

**Third**, using the `money` filter, only two trailing zeroes will be kept.

```
Input: {{ 2040.002020203 | money }}

Ouput: {{ $20.40 }}
```

Comment: This is fine but I still can't get it to work, the issue is because it is trying to display a string as money and it doesn't work, so I need to convert the string to a number which seems impossible in liquid script. I'm not using Shopify I'm using dotmailer but should be similar process.

Comment: I could of course amend my data to display the formatted string as money when it goes into dotmailer (and thus not needing to use liquid script) but this will be a much bigger job because I have to change a lot of code and do more testing, it also make sense to do the formatting in the email (in liquid script in dotmailer)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'm getting as output from your liquid code on my test store:

```
teststring: 202.2400 
testnumeric: 202.24 
teststring as money: Liquid error: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) 
testnumeric as money: Liquid error: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) 
test convert teststring to numeric: 247.24 
test show above as money: Liquid error: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

Changing the `| money: "GBP"` filter to be simply `| money` (how Shopify normally uses the filter) gives:

```
teststring: 202.2400 
testnumeric: 202.24 
teststring as money: $2.02 !! 
testnumeric as money: $2.02 !! 
test convert teststring to numeric: 247.24 
test show above as money: $2.47 !!
```

... which seems to be working as intended.  (And yes, my dev store's shop.money_format is currently `${{ amount }} !!`. It amused me at some point.)

Are you trying to use these liquid statements in the context of an app? If so, there may be a problem with that app's interpretation of the liquid code - but as you can see, from a purely Shopify standpoint, your code should be working exactly as expected (both with and without converting the string to a number)  I would recommend contacting your app supplier to complain that things aren't working the way they should.

Comment: Thanks Dave B, yes it is via dotmailer and so it has to be their implementation as I've tried everything. I've resolved this now by sending the decimal as a string pre-formatted as currency - not ideal but it was a workaround. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, using formatted strings in place of numbers makes me cringe - but it sounds like dotmailer has forced your hand in this.  Glad you were able to get something working!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only positive numbers, you can use the [`abs` filter](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/math-filters#abs) to convert the String to a number. This should the work like this:

```
{% assign teststring = '202.2400' %}
teststring as money: {{ teststring | abs | money: "GBP" }}
```

Of course, this only works correctly if the number is already positive.

Comment: I've tried this but it is not converted to money e.g. output is:`teststring as money: 202.2400`

Comment: It is treated like the existing string where it isn't shown as money. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198710/convert-string-to-integer-in-shopify-liquid) you should be able to do:

```
{% assign teststring =  '202.2400' %}
{% assign testnum = teststring | times: 100 %}
teststring as money {{ testnum | money }}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. You have the syntax slightly wrong too but anyway it is obviously still treating it as text as if I change to times: 2 I get: `teststring as money 202.2400202.2400`. I can't believe it's so difficult to convert from string to number what sort of language is this. You have to use a hack and even that doesn't work lol.

Comment: Sorry. Typed in hasted. Fixed and tested.