# Shopify - Convert Int to String in Liquid

Tags: string, integer, shopify, liquid, coercion

How do you change the datatype from a number to a string in liquid?

This could be used to create dynamic css classes within blocks. However, if it comes through as an integer it isn't recognized as a class.

```
{{block.id}} // Integer
```

I have answered my own question below along with an example.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: There's already a question with an answer for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198710/convert-string-to-integer-in-shopify-liquid If that doesn't solve it you could go to the shopify community: https://community.shopify.com/ Or just ask google there are plenty of answers there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to integer in Shopify Liquid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198710/convert-string-to-integer-in-shopify-liquid)

Comment: @Leo, the OP is wanting to do the exact opposite of the questions you have linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotation marks...

```
{% for block in section.blocks %}
  {% assign blockId = "{{block.id}}" %}
  <style>
    .{{blockId}} .text-color {
      color: {{block.settings.text_color}}
    }
  </style>

  <div class="{{blockId}}">
    <span class="text-color">I am whatever color you set me to</span>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: To go the opposite way then and get a number from a string you can use a math filter on it.

Comment: It is not working in Braze. Following code works.
{% assign blockId = block.id | append: "" %}

Answer (score 8):

For me `| string` wasn't working so I've used this

```
{% assign variant_id = variant.id | append: "" %}
```

Comment: In Braze its working

Comment: This makes no sense. Wouldn't this produce `id""`?

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution, just cast it:

```
{% assign valueyouwant = intValue | string %}
```

Seems to work well. :)